# LAST_INSERT_ID returns 0 in an insert query

Tags: mysql

Please I am trying to insert the last ID into a different column of the same row in mysql. This is what i have tried

```
 Insert Query

"INSERT INTO table(char,name) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'KOKO')"

This is the Output
ID  |   char    |   name    |
1   |    0      |   KOKO    |
```

HOWEVER, I expect that when a row is inserted the column `char` will insert the `ID` value as well; What i expect

```
    ID  |   char    |   name    |
    1   |    1      |   KOKO    |
```

Please is there something i am doing wrong. Will be glad to know, thanks in advance

Comment: Is your `ID` column your Primary Key? Is it set to Auto Increment?

Comment: How can LAST_INSERT_ID() know the LAST_INSERT_ID before there is a LAST_INSERT_ID from an insert? (i.e. its evaluated *before* the INSERT in your example)

Comment: I think the function LAST_INSERT_ID() is intended for use after an insert. Try adding more rows, if you get consistently 1 less than you expect then add one to LAST_INSERT_ID(). If that does not work you will need to fill in char in an update after the insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and insert in the same transaction because `LAST_INSERT_ID()` do not know value of the last insert id before insert 
Please try to use update:

```
INSERT INTO table(char,name) VALUES (0,'KOKO')
UPDATE table
SET char = LAST_INSERT_ID()
WHERE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: I would suggest UPDATE table SET char = ID or you`ll just update one row.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns a generated value that was set for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the most recently executed INSERT statement. Therefore you need this sequence: insert -> get last insert id -> update. Here is code:

```
INSERT INTO table (char, name) VALUES (0, 'KOKO')

UPDATE table SET `char` = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE `ID` = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

But it turns out that the column `char` duplicates column `ID` which possibly indicates wrong DB structure.

Comment: you could also make a trigger though